# Regex to ignore specific characters

Tags: python, regex, parsing

I am parsing a text on non alphanumeric characters and would like to exclude specific characters like apostrophes, dash/hyphens and commas.

I would like to build a regex for the following cases:

1. non-alphanumeric character, excluding apostrophes and hypens
2. non-alphanumeric character, excluding commas,apostrophes and hypens

This is what i have tried:

```
def split_text(text):
    my_text = re.split('\W',text)

    # the following doesn't work.
    #my_text = re.split('([A-Z]\w*)',text)
    #my_text = re.split("^[a-zA-Z0-9]+(-[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*$",text)

    return my_text
```

- **Case 1**:

  - **Sample Input:** What's up? It's good to see you my-friend. "Hello" to-the world!.
  - **Sample Output:** ['What's','up','It's','good','to','see','you','my-friend','Hello','to-the','world']
- **Case 2**:

  - **Sample Input:** It means that, it's not good-to do such things.
  - **Sample Output:** ['It', 'means', 'that,', 'it's', 'not', 'good-to', 'do', 'such', 'things']

Any ideas

Comment: There are some errors (not related to the question) in your code e.g. missing colon at end of first line and indents within the function itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

is this what you want?

> non-alphanumeric character, excluding apostrophes and hypens

```
my_text = re.split(r"[^\w'-]+",text)
```

> non-alphanumeric character, excluding commas,apostrophes and hypens

```
my_text = re.split(r"[^\w-',]+",text)
```

the `[]` syntax defines a character class, `[^..]` *"complements"* it, i.e. it negates it.

See the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax) about that:

> *Characters that are not within a range can be matched by complementing the set. If the first character of the set is* `'^'`, *all the characters that are not in the set will be matched. For example,* `[^5]` *will match any character except* `'5'`*, and* `[^^]` *will match any character except* `'^'`. `^` *has no special meaning if it’s not the first character in the set.*

Answer (score 3):

You can use a negated [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) for this:

```
my_text = re.split(r"[^\w'-]+",text)
```

or

```
my_text = re.split(r"[^\w,'-]+",text)   # also excludes commas
```

Comment: since zmo explanation, is it ok if I accept his answer?

Comment: @user3247054: Sure, and you don't have to ask :) (In fact, it's not even necessary to say "Thank you", upvotes are the best thank-you you can give.)